# python array form input

Tags: python, list

in Python input is `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]` form

not like integer form 1 2 3 2 3 4

but having []

in code

```
input =[]
inputfunc() //get input array
print input
```

You input

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
```

python result will print

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
```

So can I save this variable? or I must using String parsing?

Comment: `input =[]` : not using builtin names as variable names would be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval) to convert that string into a python object like this:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]')
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
>>> L=ast.literal_eval('[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]')
>>> type(L)
<class 'list'>
>>> L
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
>>>
```

`ast` stands for Abstract Syntax Tree. `literal_eval()` is much more safe than `eval()`.

Quoting from official doc:

> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string) Safely evaluate an expression node or
>   a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or
>   container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.